# an image won't be forgotten by android ide - android

Tags: android, compilation, intellij-idea

I am new to android development. I run my test app and I keep on having a compilation error message in a `values.xml` file

```
Gradle: String types not allowed (at 'myimage.jpg' with value 'myimage.jpg')
```

So I deleted the `myimage.jpg` reference from my `main.xml` file, but I keep on having the same message (I restarted my ide after cleaning the project)

Edit : here's my values.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

    <drawable name="myimage.jpg">hey_image_ny.jpg</drawable>
    <drawable name="image_ny.jpg">image_ny.jpg</drawable>
    <drawable name="oups.jpg">oups</drawable>

    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="app_name">gproject</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

and my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/oups">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your Values.xml file with your layout file.

Comment: @kaushaltrivedi I have just edited my post

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with those drawable tags? You shouldn't have drawable tags like that in your xml file.

Comment: @btse but I didn't write the `values.xml` file, it was generated by the ide I guess ? I only want to get the image as the background of my view

Comment: Can you try and remove all 3 of the xml drawable tags and see what happens.

Comment: @btse I found what was wrong. Sorry, it was just caused by some non deleted `drawable` tags..

Answer (score 0):

I get it, I had in res/drawable.xml a lot of extra_files that were supposed to be deleted, as so

```
<resources>
    <drawable name="myimage.jpg">myimage.jpg</drawable>
</resources>
```

so I deleted it and it compiled